# checking if array1 mirrors array 2

Tags: c

Here is my function.c:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

   int mirror(int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len)
    {
         for(unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
           {
               if(len == 0 || arr1[i] == arr2[i])
               { 
                     return 1;
               }
    
   
            }
 
         return 0;
      }
```

here is my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "t2mirror.h"

 int main(void) 
 int a5[7] = {5,2,2,3,4,5,5};
int a6[7] = {5,5,4,3,2,2,5};

if (mirror(a5, a6, 7) == 1) { 
    printf("a5 and a6 are mirrored\n");
} else {
    printf("a5 and a6 are NOT mirrored\n");
}

if (mirror(a5, a6, 0) == 1) { 
    printf("a5 and a6 are mirrored\n");
} else {
    printf("a5 and a6 are NOT mirrored\n");
}

int a7[2] = {1,1};
int a8[2] = {1,2};

if (mirror(a7, a8, 2) == 1) { 
    printf("a7 and a8 are mirrored\n");
} else {
    printf("a7 and a8 are NOT mirrored\n");
}

int a9[3] = {10,15,20};
int a10[3] = {10,15,20};

if (mirror(a9, a10, 3) == 1) { 
    printf("a9 and a10 are mirrored\n");
} else {
    printf("a9 and a10 are NOT mirrored\n");
}




return 0;
```

}

I need to mirror the array and check. if the array mirrored then the output mirrored should print and otherwise not mirrored. I cannot find the where I made the mistake. In the condition (a7,a8, 2) it should give the output not mirrored yet it does the opposite. similarly in (a9,a10,3) it should give not mirrored. can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is your function supposed to do? Right now it checks if there's at least one identical element.

Comment: `if(len == 0` needs to be tested outside the loop, else it's useless and will fail to compare arrays of len 0 as equal

Comment: Won't `memncmp()` achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: plus the main issue: it tells OK when there's one identical element. Which is the inverse of what you want

Comment: In addition, you have to check `arr1[i] != arr2[len - 1 - i]`

Comment: You really need to clarify what the function should do. Voting to close this for unclear.

Comment: @klutt I am sorry for not writing the question properly. I am new to learning to code and not very good at asking questions(English is not my first language). I tried framing as much as I could. However, I'll take a good look at the question before asking in the future.

Comment: @HarsimarKaur That's good, but please [edit] this question too.

Comment: @klutt i did it already and whatever I have written that is the question...if your array is mirrored cout << mirrored and if not then cout << NOT mirrored.

Comment: @HarsimarKaur Exactly what does "mirrored" mean?

Comment: @klutt say you have an array a1[3] = {10, 15 ,20} and a2[3] = {20, 15, 10}. now, imagine if there's a mirror in the centre of both of these arrays, like                 {10, 15, 20} | {20, 15, 10} (that line is a mirror)...so, if the a2 "mirrors" a1, then the you get it true otherwise false.

Comment: @HarsimarKaur So mirrored means that it's the same when it's reversed?

Comment: @klutt No. mirrored means your array is laterally inverted.

Answer (score 0):

`if(len == 0 || arr1[i] == arr2[i])`

The len == 0 check shouldn't be inside the loop. You can probably remove it entirely. Apart from that, you are just checking if the arrays have an item in common at the same index - that doesn't match the algorithm your describe.

You should rather check when the first item in arr1 doesn't match the corresponding one in arr2. That is:

```
if(arr1[i] != arr2[len-i-1])
{
  return 0;
}
...

return 1; // at the end of the function, if we got here then all items matched
```

Comment: and if I had used two loops one going forward and the other backward...it would have done the same thing?

Comment: @HarsimarKaur Yeah that works too. Performance might be slightly different, but that's typically nothing for beginners to concern themselves with. A nested inner loop like `for(int j=len-1; j>=0; j--) if(arr1[i] != arr2[j])` would likely be slightly less efficient, but that's an advanced topic.

Comment: I tried doing that as well, but instead of starting j with len -1 i did it with len and when the output didn't come out as expected I thought that's a wrong process. Should've looked a bit more carefully.